# Woocommerce (Checkout-Page) - Replace content after placing order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

This question is related to the `thankyou page`.

> **I created my own custom thank you layout, and it has a shortcode which is `[custom-thankyou-054]`.**

-
Normally, when you done placing your order the checkout page will tell you a `Thank you. Your order has been received.` and some of the details about your order.

I don't want to show all of those details. I designed a simple yet more interactive layout and I want to use it instead.

I wonder if there is a hook to do that?

I know a hook to redirect to another page after placing the order.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_redirectcustom');

function bbloomer_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = 'https://yoursite.com/custom-url';
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that is not my case. I wanted the user to stay on that `checkout page` but only change its content with my custom layout after placing the order, something like:

```
add_action( '??????????', 'change_checkout_page_content_after_placing_order'); 
function change_checkout_page_content_after_placing_order( $order_id ){
 return do_shortcode('[custom-thankyou-054]');
}
```

is that possible?

Comment: You can override the default Woocommerce `thank you page` in your theme. Then keep the functionality you want integrated with your custom layout

Comment: I actually tried that, but I edited the checkout page using Elementor. I add some elements to it to make it more interactive. Then after editing the thank you page and placing the order, it doesn't change the contents but only removes the billing form and adds the thank you page content to it.

Comment: How do you add some elements to your `checkout` page? What elements did you add? Is it in the top of the checkout form or at the bottom of checkout form? Tell us more...

Comment: I'm using Elementor to edit the checkout page. Then I just drag and drop some elements in the top of the Shortcode widget with the code `['woocommerce_checkout']`.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong, but you are close enough.

Do not add elements to your checkout page directly with Elementor. Since you just want to add elements at the top and bottom of checkout form, then you can do it using the hook `woocommerce_before_checkout_form` for the top of the checkout form and `woocommerce_after_checkout_form` for the bottom of the checkout form.

If you really want to use Elementor to design the elements of the top and bottom of your checkout form, then I suggest doing it the way how you created your thankyou template then use its shortcode.

For example, you created a template designed for the top and bottom of the checkout form, and the shortcode is something like `[my-top-design]` and `[my-bottom-design]`. Then go to your `function.php` and do the following.

```
/** This will add your template designed for the top of the checkout form **/
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'custom_top_checkout_form');
function custom_top_checkout_form(){
    echo do_shortcode('[my-top-design]');
    /**You can also insert an html tag here instead of the shortcode of your template..**/
    // echo '<h2>Some top elements...</h2>';
}

/** This will add your template designed for the bottom of the checkout form **/
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'custom_bottom_checkout_form');
function custom_bottom_checkout_form(){
    echo do_shortcode('[my-bottom-design]');
    /**You can also insert an html tag here instead of the shortcode of your template..**/
    // echo '<h2>Some bottom elements...</h2>';
}
```

After placing the order, all of the checkout form including the top and bottom elements will be gone and will replace it with the thankyou page.

Now, with your thankyou page, you can override it by using [WooCommerce template override](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Copy the: 
[/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/checkout/thankyou.php).

Into your active theme, it should be something like this: 
`/wp-content/themes/activetheme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php`

Then edit the `thankyou.php` and remove the unnecessary information in replace with your custom thankyou template using the shortcode again.

It will be something like this.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>

<div class="woocommerce-order">

    <?php if ( $order ) :

        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>

        <?php if ( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed"><?php esc_html_e( 'Unfortunately your order cannot be processed as the originating bank/merchant has declined your transaction. Please attempt your purchase again.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed-actions">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php esc_html_e( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php esc_html_e( 'My account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>

        <?php else : ?>
            <?php 
                //your custom template here...
                echo do_shortcode('[custom-thankyou-054]'); 
            ?>  
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', esc_html__( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), null ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: How about the checkout form? I added a border shadow to it?

Comment: You can do using `CSS`, use the class name `form.checkout.woocommerce-checkout`. For example `form.checkout.woocommerce-checkout{border: solid 1px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 4x 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)}`.